# shadow_hand spawn on gazebo electric don't move

Tags: gazebo, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i have an haptic glove, and im using it to move the fingers of the shadow hand spawn on gazebo electric.
first i was working on fuerte and doesn't a problem all was good, but i have to down to electric for collision part that i need and on fuerte gazebo version is broken.

the values of sensors are publishing on this topics

```
sh_mfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
  sh_mfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
  sh_lfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
  sh_lfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
  sh_ffj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
  sh_ffj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
```

well, the same sh_xf#_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command for the 5 fingers.

to spawn shadow_hand i use

roslaunch sr_hand gazebo_hand.launch

EDIT:
well i'm thinking is an error or here miss something. see when i run this on fuerte the rxgraph show me the node of the communication and the publishin on the topics of contrtollers like see in the image [image: 13602518696733189.png]

but it electric is happenin this
[image: 13602519093756814.png]

here is like the hand looks after some minutes, and nothing happens when is running rostopic pub [image: 13602540074049493.png]

Log when run roslaunch sr_hand gazebo_hand.launch

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/ff663bbf8666674767dfb29736cdaf8d

Answer of the `rosmake shadow_robot`

```
virtualtouch@ubuntu:~/shadow$ rosmake shadow_robot
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                           
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['shadow_robot']                                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/virtualtouch/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130212-115421
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['shadow_robot'] to:
['sr_hand', 'sr_mechanism_model', 'sr_mechanism_controllers', 'sr_move_arm', 'sr_utilities', 'sr_hardware_interface', 'sr_kinematics', 'sr_movements', 'sr_example', 'sr_tactile_sensors', 'sr_description', 'sr_robot_msgs', 'sr_gazebo_plugins']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> hardware_interface [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sr_kinematics [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> sr_move_arm [ make ]                                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< hardware_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package hardware_interface     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime 4 Active 13/118 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs
 No Makefile in package std_srvs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs
 No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package trajectory_msgs
 No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_controllers_msgs [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_controllers_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_controllers_msgs 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_mechanism_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_mechanism_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_mechanism_msgs
 No Makefile in package pr2_mechanism_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sr_robot_msgs [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
 No Makefile in package angles
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
 No Makefile in package tf          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
 No Makefile in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_updater
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test
 No Makefile in package self_test
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
 No Makefile in package console_bridge
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdfdom_headers [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdfdom_headers ROS_NOBUILD in package urdfdom_headers
 No Makefile in package urdfdom_headers
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser
 No Makefile in package collada_parser
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole_bridge [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole_bridge
 No Makefile in package rosconsole_bridge
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdfdom [ make ]                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdfdom ROS_NOBUILD in package urdfdom
 No Makefile in package urdfdom
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf
 No Makefile in package urdf    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_msgs [ make ]                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_msgs                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_hardware_interface [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_hardware_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_hardware_interface
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sr_hardware_interface [ make ]                                   
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesr_kinematics: 2.2 sec ] [ sr_move_... [ 4 Active 55/118 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package sr_kinematics
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests sr_kinematics
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'sr_kinematics' depends on non-existent package 'kinematics_msgs' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'sr_kinematics'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sr_kinematics written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/virtualtouch/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130212-115421/sr_kinematics/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sr_kinematics [FAIL] [ 2.24 seconds ]                            
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sr_kinematics. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesr_move_arm: 2.3 sec ] [ sr_robot_m... [ 3 Active 55/118 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package sr_move_arm
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests sr_move_arm
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'sr_move_arm' depends on non-existent package 'arm_navigation_msgs' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'sr_move_arm'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sr_move_arm written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/virtualtouch/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130212-115421/sr_move_arm/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< sr_move_arm [FAIL] [ 2.34 seconds ]                              
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sr_move_arm. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sr_hardware_interface [PASS] [ 9.12 seconds ]                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sr_robot_msgs [PASS] [ 66.42 seconds ]                           
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Built 59 packages with 2 failures.                                            
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                   
[ rosmake ] /home/virtualtouch/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130212-115421
```

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54624/shadow_hand-spawn-on-gazebo-electric-don%27t-move/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install arm_navigation stack and you should be able to build:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-arm-navigation
rosmake shadow_robot
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1